# Is there a way to add Columns after writing sheet data without causing the app to hung?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

We are using OpenXML to create the excel file and among other things we want to write the `Columns` OpenXMLElement after ending with the SheetData object, given that the Columns element has to be written before the SheetData one for the Excel to open it.

I have tried to use:

1. `worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAt(new Columns(this._columnList), 1);`
2. `worksheetPart.Worksheet.Descedants<SheetData>().First()` then use the InsertBefore() method on the resulted object

There is a lot of memory consumption for large sheets and the creation never completes.

Is there a more efficient way to do that using OpenXML?